# enum in stringWithFormat provokes incompatible pointer type warning

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, enums, stringwithformat

I have an enum property:

```
typedef enum syncCodeTypes {
    kCodeNull, 
    kCodeFoo,
    kCodeBar,
    kCodeDone
} syncCodeType;

//...

@property syncCodeType syncCode;
```

I use it in a `stringWithFormat:`:

```
[self showAlertWithMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"Sync Error", @"Sync Error") andInfo:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString("Heads up re foobar code %d.", "Heads up re foobar code %d."), self.syncCode]];
```

…and get this warning:

> Passing argument 1 of localizedStringForKey:value:table from incompatible pointer type.

Same thing happens if I substitue the unsigned conversion specifier (`%u` instead of `%d`).
The compiler doesn’t like `%lu`, `%ld`, `%llu`, or `%lld` either.

Other posts regarding a related language advise that enums are neither signed nor unsigned, so I tried explicitly casting the enum to a signed and to an unsigned integer — and got exactly the same error message:

```
NSInteger iSyncCode = self.syncCode;
[self showAlertWithMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"Sync Error", @"Sync Error") andInfo:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(“Heads up re foobar code %d.", “Heads up re foobar code %d."), iSyncCode]];
// compiler still annoyed

NSUInteger uSyncCode = self.syncCode;
[self showAlertWithMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"Sync Error", @"Sync Error") andInfo:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(“Heads up re foobar code %u.”, “Heads up re foobar code %u.”), uSyncCode]];
// compiler still annoyed
```

In runtime there’s no problem — for now. But I'd like to be kosher. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest prefixing your type with capital letter(s).  Will avoid confusion with variable names in code.

Comment: I thought only class names should be capitalized -- although, yes, structs like NSRect are capitalized. Personally, when I see a cap, I start looking for corresponding h/m files, so I'd prefer to leave this as is. But for others who want to follow your suggestion, which should be capped, "syncCodeTypes" or "syncCodeType" or both?

Comment: Generally, types and non-tansients -- #defines, statics, etc... -- are capitalized (with a prefix).  And, yeah, when you see MyStruct, you *should* look for the header file because that is *most likely* where the definition should be (or at the top of the .m).  In any case, a capital says "this is a type that is defined somewhere else" and a lowercase letter (camelCased) is "this is a variable that holds a copy of or reference to the thing that is defined elsewhere".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `@`-sign before the strings in `NSLocalizedString`.

Replace `"Heads up re foobar code %d."` with `@"Heads up re foobar code %d."`.

Comment: Aach, you're right. The whole problem was the lack of the "@"s. It had nothing to do with the enum. I'm surprised it compiled at all.

Answer (score 1):

The `%d` format specifier is for `int` variables. But `self.syncCode` is not an `int`, it is an `syncCodeType`.

You need to cast the value to an `int`:

```
(int)self.syncCode
```

or the whole line:

```
[self showAlertWithMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"Sync Error", @"Sync Error") andInfo:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Heads up re foobar code %d.", @"Heads up re foobar code %d."), (int)self.syncCode]];
```

This will make the compiler happy.

P.S. And as phix23 points out, you need to pass `NSString` literals, not C-string literals to `NSLocalizedString`.

Comment: That's a more elegant way of casting to int than doing `NSInteger iSyncCode = self.syncCode;' as I tried in my question. But in fact casting is not necessary; once I add the "@" to make the formatted string an NSString, the warning goes away.